# What do the points of infinite capacitance in the featured circuit represent and how do we model and implement them?

Tags: transistors

I am trying to learn more about transistor and analog amplifiers and I found some labs online and I am completing them. Throughout the schematic, there are points of infinite capacitance. Is this modeling built in capacitance or capacitors added into the circuit? Also, if the latter is the case, do we model and implement this by using very large capacitors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they are doing is showing all of the coupling and bypass capacitors as infinite so they don’t limit the low frequency response. You can think of them as a short circuit for any AC signal and an open circuit for the DC bias.

To model them you could just use a large value like 1 farad. In the real world the rule of thumb is to use caps that have an impedance 1/10th or less of the other impedances at that point in the circuit at the lowest frequency you want to amplify. For instance if an emitter resistor is 470 ohms make it’s bypass cap impedance no more than 47 ohms at your low frequency point.